# Any techniques to solve analytically or estimate $\int_2^N \cos ^N\left(\frac{2 \pi N}{m}\right) \, dm $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, estimation

I was wondering if there was a way to solve,

$$\int_2^N \cos ^N\left(\frac{2 \pi  a}{m}\right) \, dm \,\,(1)$$ 
or if more tractable$$\int_2^N \cos ^N\left(\frac{2 \pi  N}{m}\right) \, dm \,\,(2)$$

using non numeric integration techniques?

I've just started this very nice open access epub book [Copley, Leslie
Mathematics for the Physical Sciences](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/449524),

now in Chapter 6 - Asymptotic Expansions, there are methods for estimating difficult integrals.

Would this technique or some other estimation technique work on (1) or (2)?

Perhaps increasing the upper limit well beyond N as suggested in that chapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming $N$ is a positive integer.  You can expand $\cos^N(x)$ as a linear combination of $\cos(kx)$ for $k$ from $0$ to $N$, and use 
$$ \int \cos(2\pi a/m)\; dm =  m \cos(2\pi a/m) + 2 \pi a\; \text{Si}(2 \pi a/m) + c$$
where Si is the [sine-integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral).

Comment: This is what @Robert Israel is referring to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae